# Sorting a 2D numpy array on to the proximity of each element to a certain point

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have (n,2) numpy array which contains the coordination of n points now I want to sort them based on approximation of each element to the specific point (x,y) and pick the closest one. How can I achieve this?

Right now I have:

```
def find_nearest(array,value):
    xlist = (np.abs(array[:, 0]-value[:, 0]))
    ylist = (np.abs(array[:, 1]-value[:, 1]))
    newList = np.vstack((xlist,ylist))
    // SORT NEW LIST and return the 0 elemnt
```

In my solution I need to sort newList based on Proximity to (0,0) and I don't know how? Any solution for this or any other solution?

My array of points looks like:

```
array([[ 0.1648,  0.227 ],
       [ 0.2116,  0.2472],
       [ 0.78  ,  0.546 ],
       [ 0.9752,  1.    ],
       [ 0.384 ,  0.4862],
       [ 0.4428,  0.2204],
       [ 0.4448,  0.4146],
       [ 0.1046,  0.2658],
       [ 0.5668,  0.7792],
       [ 0.1664,  0.0746],
       [ 0.5636,  0.6372],
       [ 0.7822,  0.5536],
       [ 0.7718,  0.8276],
       [ 0.9916,  1.    ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.    ],
       [ 0.8206,  0.817 ],
       [ 0.4858,  0.4652],
       [ 0.    ,  0.    ],
       [ 0.1574,  0.3114],
       [ 0.    ,  0.0022],
       [ 0.874 ,  0.714 ],
       [ 0.148 ,  0.6624],
       [ 0.0656,  0.5912],
       [ 0.1148,  0.607 ],
       [ 0.069 ,  0.6296]])
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the cartesian distance you can do something like the following:

```
def find_nearest(arr,value):
    newList = arr - value
    sort = np.sum(np.power(newList, 2), axis=1)
    return newList[sort.argmin()]
```

I am assuming `newList` has a shape of (n,2). As a note I changed the input variable `array` to `arr` to avoid issues if numpy is imported like: `from numpy import *`.

Answer (score 6):

Sorting to find the nearest point is not a good idea. If you want the closest point then just find the closest point instead, sorting for that is overkilling.

```
def closest_point(arr, x, y):
    dist = (arr[:, 0] - x)**2 + (arr[:, 1] - y)**2
    return arr[dist.argmin()]
```

Moreover if you need to repeat the search many times with a fixed or quasi fixed set of points there are specific data structures that can speed up this kind of query a lot (the search time becomes sub-linear).

Answer (score 2):

If you have scipy the following works:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as ds
import numpy as np

pointOfInterest = np.array([[0, 0]])
```

Then:

```
arr[ds.cdist(pointOfInterest, arr)[0].np.argsort()[0]]
```

`arr` is your array above.

Comment: I think you have a typo above. The second block should be `arr[np.argsort(ds.cdist(pointOfInterest, arr)[0])[0]]`.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using the key parameter in `sorted`?

```
sorted(p, key = lambda (a,b) :(a-m)**2+(b-n)**2)
```

Here `p` is of the form `array([[1,2], [3,4], ...])` and `(m,n)` is the tuple of the slowest point ...

Comment: This returns a list of arrays. You can always convert it to the right form by wrapping the entire expression in an `np,array()` statement ...